# Visual Studios 2013 indenting code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, indentation, visual-studio-sdk

It's not necessary I fix this 'issue' since it's a more aesthetic thing. I was just wondering if it's possible to indent code that comes under the "public:" deceleration after indenting the deceleration itself.

So it would look like this:

```
class Myclass{
    public:
        void test(){
        }
}
```

At the moment the void part would be directly underneath the public modifier. I have looked through the formatting setting and yet cannot find how to do this.

Comment: I just tried in VS2012 - and the default indentation looks as you describe. What is the actual problem? can you post how does it look (maybe a picture)?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/45yw2x

Comment: @NirMH You can see how the public modifier is in-line with the class identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio open Tools/Options. In the menu on the left choose Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting. There you can change a lot of things like indentation.

Comment: there is a part that lets you indent access modifiers `public`, `protected` and `private`, so it will have the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Doing that just makes `public` and `void` in line with each other

Comment: I assume you'd like the code to look like this? http://prntscr.com/45yw2x
Then you'll have to uncheck "indent access specifiers" in formatthing/indentation.

Comment: Yes but I was hoping for public  to be indented once and void to be indented (and any other code after it) to be indented twice. I suppose it doesn't work any other way then?

Comment: Aha, I see. I don't think so, or at least not that I know.

Comment: Well, it doesn't effect the code so I guess that's no problem then. Thanks for the help anyway rashmatash.